# Как привести все дробные числа к одному формату?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Допустим у нас есть массив дробных чисел **[5.112312, 3.43, 2.0000000001, 4.3333]**.

> Как сделать так, чтобы все числа в данном массиве были с K знаками после запятой?

В С++ есть функция printf("%0.kf", number), которая приводит числа к "k" знакам после запятой и выводит, но все бы хорошо, только мне нужно все числа запоминать в массив.

Например для массива упомянутого выше и числа *k = 6* исходный массив будёт : **[5, 112312, 3.430000, 2.000000, 4.333300]**.

*1 <= k <= 16*

Comment: Может есть какая нибудь встроенная функция в С++?

Comment: Вы не запоминаете числа "с К знаками" (разве что если вы их храните как *строки*). Их можно только *вывести* с К знаками. см. `setprecision`, если надо для С++. Запоминаются они все в бинарном представлении в памяти...

Comment: *Число к "k" знакам после запятой* - это вам нужны fixed point числа, которые в С++ из коробки не поддерживаются. Но вообще-то у меня есть сильные подозрения, что это проблема XY

Comment: Сорян за плохой русский, если их можно только выводить то это оччень плохо)

Comment: Почему плохо?! Поясните.

Comment: "нужно все числа запоминать в массив" - значит это будет массив строк

Comment: я решая задачу с геометрии, наткнулся на проблему, мне нужно чтобы все дробные числа были равны, и я их кидал в set, но увы в set е я увидел числа [0,7170019, 0,7170019] вот и не могу решить проблему...

Comment: Ощущение, что вы спрашиваете, не как забивать гвозди, а как держать микроскоп, забивая гвозди... Может, давайте рассмотрим вашу проблему с самого начала? Не то, как вы ее хотите решать, а то, в чем состоит изначальная задача?

Comment: Придумайте какой-либо другой способ решения задачи, не опирающийся на **точное** сравнение **вещественных** чисел

Comment: @Harry Уже все понятно. В вычислениях (разных) получаются числа (координаты точек), которые (по смыслу, с погрешностью) одни и те же. А они не одни и те же.

Comment: то бишь нету функции которая приводить числа к одному формату?

Comment: У числа нет формата (в том смысле, в котором Вы это понимаете). Формат есть у строкового представления числа. Но я уже сказал, что Вам следует делать.

Comment: Тут у нас явно разное понимание термина **формат**. Они все в одном формате - IEEE-что-то-там. Предлагаю - множьте на 1000000 и переводите в целое (можно с округлением). И работайте с целыми. Или делите на 1000000. Но **реально** это все равно будут числа с какими-нибудь ненулевыми 15-16 знаками...

Comment: а как это будёт выглядеть в одной строке на С++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кладите в `set` числа, которые получаются после перевода первоначальных чисел в строку с шестью цифрами после запятой и считывания чисел обратно из этой строки.

---

```
a = round(a * 1000000) / 1000000;
```

---

*... задачу ПО геометрии ...*

Comment: А не быстрее будет множить на 1000000, обрезать (округлять) к целому и делить на 1000000? Чем через строку туда-сюда прогонять...

Comment: @Harry Конечно быстрее. Но так автор сможет на эти свои числа *посмотреть*.

Comment: Так ему нужны шашечки или нужно ехать? :)

Comment: @Harry Ехать на машине с шашечками. :)